# Use/See whole the flash memory space

Tags: filesystems, memory, flash-memory, file-metadata

When we bought a N Giga Byte flash memory, the free space that the OS provide for us, is less than N GigaBytes. For example, for a 2 GB flash memory, total space that we can use, is 1.86 GB. 
[image]

As far as I know, the difference is for metadata. Is that right?

**My question :**

Is there any command or program in linux, to see or use whole the 2GB space?
can I see those metadata and filesystems?

Appreciate your time and consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturer sold you the 2GB USB stick as 2 Gigabytes, meaning 2000000000 bytes.  Your computer is showing the stick in units of Gigibytes.  1 Gigibyte is 1024 x 1024 x 1024 bytes, which is 1073741824 bytes.

If you divide your 2000000000 by 1073741824 you'll end up with 1.86264514923095703125 or, rounded to two decimal places 1.86 GiB.

In other words, 2GB = 1.86GiB

Computers tend to work with GiB as it's a multiple of 2 (1 GiB = 2^30) while humans (and disk manufacturers [who are human after all]) work with GB as it's a multiple of 10 (1 GB = 10^9)

Comment: +1 The norm when referring to memory or data streams is a power of two value (1024).  But the norm when referring to storage is the decimal tidy 1000.  Hence, a 2 GB filesystem is 2 billion bytes exactly.  Whoever wrote this tool is being stubborn, because I'm sure that issue has been pointed out before.  1.87 GB is *wrong* in this context.

Comment: @goldilocks Is this not simply an issue of developers not using the correct units? If the developer of the tool used by the OP changed it to display `GiB` instead of `GB` it would be correct. Similarly, the RAM stick marked `2Gb` in my computer is technically `2GiB` regardless of the fact that it's memory and the manufacturer stamped `2GB` on it? Are USB stick and SDCards memory or storage? Which should they use? If everyone simply used to correct units, then there would be no confusion. `1.86GB` is wrong in all contexts - `2000000000` is either `1.86GiB` or `2GB`.

Comment: I did not know `GiB` meant anything special, but there you go: IEC/ISO bonified.  That makes it even more wrong, I agree.  Either the dev actually doesn't know, has never taken the criticism seriously enough to listen, or is a dedicated outlier WRT to unit notation, lol.  Hmmm, in fact I have some public software kicking around that outputs 1024 values with "MB" and "GB"...better fix that.  Eventually.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the space used by the file system. There is a space overhead for both metadata and the file system's internal structure. This is true of virtually all file systems whether they are Windows or Linux file systems.

On linux, storage devices such as your ssd are treated as a block devices and there is a command 'dd' that will address entire block devices; you could use 'dd' to copy the entire content of the 2GB stick into a 2GB file on another storage device if you wished. You could also use dd to put it back on another device of the same size.

However you are never likely to be able to use the whole 2GB in a practical manner, as generally you would be accessing information via a file system, all of which have an overhead.

If your are interested in pursuing this there is plenty of information about file systems and the 'dd' command on the Internet. Have a play.

Comment: The reserved space is 5% by default with `ext` filesystems, but I don't think FAT does this at all.  Also, the tool is showing a capacity of 2 billion bytes -- it would be pretty strange if it gave a number of bytes *including* the reserved space, and then a number of GB that excluded it.